# Is my green pickled garlic edible?

Tags: food-safety

I tried pickling some garlic in turmeric and the garlic turned green. Just wondering if I should toss or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Garlic produces non-toxic allicin and allicin in the pickling process. When allicin and allicin are mixed together, the garlic becomes a hundred green.
The pickled garlic turns green not because the pickled garlic contains chlorophyll, which will produce green when exposed to sunlight like a plant, but because the garlic produces non-toxic allicin and allicin, allicin and garlic in the pickling Mixing the yellow pigments turns the garlic into green. After answering the questionnaire, the antioxidative ability of allicin is very strong. Therefore, eating green pickled garlic is not only non-toxic, but also has the effect of strengthening the body.

Comment: "Non-toxic allicin and allicin" does not make sense.  Probably the fault of translation software rendering two different related molecules as the same word.  You could put the original Japanese for the molecules in parenthesis and expand in prose what those 2 different molecules are.  But you can leave "a hundred green"; that is good.